# FFT - function only in sine series? Can be done with MKL / Lapack?

Tags: lapack, fftw

please can I ask, how one can make from function sine series (Fourier transform) with MKL? I can do "normal" exponential FFT with MKL (Lapack of course), how can I say that I want only sine series?
Many thanks

Comment: oh, finally I have found the mkl_trig_transform... great, I will try it ;)

Comment: You can also use the FFTW 3 interface to Fourier Transforms in the MKL: http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html#Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029

Comment: Do you mean the discrete sine transform? Look for DST.